How to check if an object is a Set in Joi?
how to create a Joi validation to check a Set type? my object does contains a field with a new Set([]) type, but using Joi.array().unique throws an error when validating.
const data = { name: "Thank you", mode: new Set(["happy"]) };

const dataSchema = Joi.object({
   name: Joi.string().required(),
   mode: Joi.array().unique().items(Joi.string())
})

but when calling dataSchema.validate(data) it throws an error "mode" must be an array

As the name suggests it expects an array, it does not matter that you also require that array to have set properties. You can use Joi.extend to create a custom validator that accepts values of type Set.

Use the object() schema, and then check that it's an instance of the Set prototype.
mode: Joi.object().instance(Set)

I can't find a way to specify the type of the set elements. You could use the extension mechanism to define your own schema for set of strings.
